# Unable to save Jupyter Notebooks locally when running within a Docker Container

Tags: docker, save, dockerfile, jupyter, mount

Here's my Dockerfile...

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
EXPOSE 38080
RUN ["mkdir", "nb"]
CMD ["jupyter", "lab", "--ip='0.0.0.0'", "--port=38080", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]
```

note that `RUN ["mkdir", "nb"]` is residual code which shouldn't impact these results

here are my Git Bash commands...

```
docker build -t jupyterlab .
docker run -p 38080:38080 -v $(pwd)/nb:/home/jovyan/work jupyterlab
```

i've also tried...

```
docker run -p 38080:38080 -v $(pwd)/nb:/home/jovyan jupyterlab
```

and one other version where i actually mount to the nb directory i created in the Dockerfile

in all cases, a notebook file created in jupyter does not save to the mounted local directory and i'm baffled as to why.

I'm running Windows 10. logged in locally (i.e. not connected to any domain) as an admin.

Comment: @HarshManvar - thanks for the formatting! much appreciated and very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with some help...

```
docker run -p 38080:38080 -v /$(pwd)/nb://home/ jupyterlab
```

the trick is the additional forward slash in front of the "$" and "/home"